# Dataframe traversing python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Data for bank account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oc3v.png)

```
accntid    transcode    transamt balance
1            Credit        20      4000
1            Debit         50
1            Credit        80
2            Debit         60      5000
2            Credit        40
2            Debit         120
2            Credit        130
```

Hi guys..I have a dataframe having above data and I want to update balance based on transaction code and transaction amount in next row. Any idea how can I traverse back and forth on Dataframe

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: First, clean your column. It's hard to identify the information in your dataframe

Comment: @PradeepPatil What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df1 = df.assign(transamt = np.where(df['transcode'] == 'Debit',-1,1) * df['transamt'])

df1['balance1'] = (df1.balance
                    .fillna(df1.groupby('accntid', group_keys=False)
                               .apply(lambda x: x.balance.fillna(df1.transamt).cumsum())))

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   accntid transcode  transamt  balance  balance1
0        1    Credit        20   4000.0    4000.0
1        1     Debit       -50      NaN    3950.0
2        1    Credit        80      NaN    4030.0
3        2     Debit       -60   5000.0    5000.0
4        2    Credit        40      NaN    5040.0
5        2     Debit      -120      NaN    4920.0
6        2    Credit       130      NaN    5050.0
```